# Cómo puedo convertir un string a otro en Laravel?

Tags: laravel

Estoy trabajando con relaciones polimórficas en **Laravel 5.6**  y necesito convetir el campo que almacena el modelo (recibe un `string`). Por ejemplo  recibo `"App/User"` y lo quiero mostrar  `"Usuarios"`.

Comment: Bienvenido a [Stack Overflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/). Está bien que recurras a la comunidad para preguntar y recibir propuestas que ayuden a responder tu inquietud, pero para que la respuesta pueda ser de buena calidad y logre responder tu inquietud necesitamos que compartas la parte del código que está relacionada con tu inquietud. Además, necesitas incluir algún ejemplo de lo que necesitas y explicar más detalladamente tu inquietud. Te recomiendo leer este artículo: [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

En `resources/lang/es` crea un archivo que se llame `models.php`

Dentro de models.php:

```
<?php

return [
    'models' => [
        'user' => 'Usuarios',
    ],
];
```

Por último, crea una función que convierta la instancia del modelo a un string traducido:

```
public function transModel($model)
{
    $model = snake_case(class_basename($model));
    return trans("models.models.{$model}");
}
```

Es solo una idea, la acabo de escribir, espero la puedas probar y sea lo que necesites.